# What is the best way to evaluate whether a string is a stringified dictionary or not

Tags: python, dictionary

I could use a regex, but am wondering if there is a better way.

For example, a value might be returned either as:

1.) `'{"username": "joe.soap", "password": "pass@word123"}'`

or

2.) `'https://www.url-example.com'`

In the case of 1.) I want to convert the contents to an actual dictionary. I am happy that I know how to do the conversion. I am stuck on how to identify 1.) without reverting to the use of regex.

**EDIT:** Because I was asked, this is how I plan to make the conversion:

```
import ast

if string_in_question == '{"username": "joe.soap", "password": "pass@word123"}':
    return ast.literal_eval(str‌​ing_in_question)
else:
    return valid_command_return‌​s
```

Comment: How do you plan on doing the conversion?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Please refer to question edit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't bother with a complex regex, simply try to convert the string to a dictionary.

I'm assuming you are using `json.loads` to do it. If the string doesn't represent a dictionary `json.loads` will raise an exception.

Note that if you do use `json.loads` the conversion will fail if the "keys" are not surrounded with double-quotes, ie trying to convert the string `"{'username': 'joe.soap', 'password': 'pass@word123'}"` to a dictionary will raise an exception as well.

```
import json

a = '{"username": "joe.soap", "password": "pass@word123"}'
b = 'https://www.url-example.com'

try:
    json.loads(a)
except ValueError:
    print("{} is not a dictionary".format(a))

try:
    json.loads(b)
except ValueError:
    print("{} is not a dictionary".format(b))
```

The output of this program will be 
`https://www.url-example.com is not a dictionary`

**UPDATE**:

When using `ast.literal_eval` the concept is the same, but you will have to catch `SyntaxError` instead of `ValueError`. Note that with `literal_eval` both single and double quotes are acceptable.

```
import ast

a = '{"username": "joe.soap", "password": "pass@word123"}'
b = "{'username': 'joe.soap', 'password': 'pass@word123'}"
c = 'https://www.url-example.com'

try:
    ast.literal_eval(a)
except SyntaxError:
    print("{} is not a dictionary".format(a))

try:
    ast.literal_eval(b)
except SyntaxError:
    print("{} is not a dictionary".format(b))

try:
    ast.literal_eval(c)
except SyntaxError:
    print("{} is not a dictionary".format(c))
```

Same as before, output is `https://www.url-example.com is not a dictionary`.

Comment: In the spirit of trying to catch the most specific error, perhaps we should try to catch `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`

Comment: Adding a check on the conversion result would discriminate between a dictionary and a list.

Comment: @mouviciel I'm not sure I'm following your comment. OP isn't interested in lists.

Comment: Now I realise my actual problem is further downstream... Even when I successfully pass a valid dictionary object, re.sub complains that it requires a string. This is scope for a separate question. If interested, I was hoping that my input, "auth": "{{ function_to_return_dict }}" would be able to pass through my script and output "auth": {"username": "joe.soap", "password": "pass@word12"}

Comment: @DeepSpace: Your assumption that I'm using json.loads is correct. My input is a Json file with certain values containing 'code' between double-quotes required by JSON. Was hoping I could on the fly swap out a JSON string for a JSON 'dictionary'

Comment: @DeepSpace, So I guess (on retrospection) I knew I could have done it this way... I tend to avoid raising exceptions (except as an extra precaution). Is this habit of mine not necessary? It's so entrenched in me that I will spend ages trying to do it the 'correct' way instead of just finding the best solution I have at the time (and potentially revisiting later).

Is there any good in using If statements, etc, etc rather than just raise an exception if it fails?

Comment: @DeanKayton In Python you will usually see the `try-except` approach rather than many `if` for sanity checks.. There is actually a term for this: [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) vs [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl)